# How to give multiple effects on photo canvas using camanjs?

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, camanjs

How to give multiple effects on photo canvas using camanjs?
My Case : "After i applied the filter effect and then add text on image the previous filter effect reverted to original image means previous effect lost from photo."

Answer (score -1):

You can make use of:

```
this.reloadCanvasData();
```